# Is this a non-polynomial problem? If not, how can it be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The problem:

> Write a function that has 2 input parameters:
>
> - `items`: a list/vector of 2-tuple positive integers (i.e. >= 1)
> - `target`: a positive integer (i.e. >= 1)
>
> Find a subset of tuples such that:
>
> - The sum of the first tuple elements of the subset is greater than or equal to the input `target`.
> - The sum of the second tuple elements of the subset is **minimal**, and let's call that sum value `best`.
>
> The function should just return `best`. Also, it is guaranteed that there is a solution. In other words, the sum of all the first tuple elements is always greater than or equal to the target.
>
> Here is the pseudocode signature of such a function:
>
> ```
> (items: List<(int, int)>, target: int) -> int
> ```
>
> And here are some examples...
>
> Example A:
>
> - items = `[(25,50), (49,51), (25,50), (1,100)]`
> - target = `50`
> - answer = `100`
>
> Example B:
>
> - items = `[(25,50), (49,51), (25,50), (1,5)]`
> - target = `50`
> - answer = `56`

Here's my naive exponential-time solution:

1. Go through all possible subsets (hence exponential time)
2. For each subset, compute the sum of the first tuple elements
3. If that sum is greater than or equal to the target, then compute the sum of the second tuple elements
4. If that new sum is the smallest found so far, update the minimum

I also tried to determine if there's a mathematical property of the problem that allows a shortcut, e.g. go through the items by the biggest "first element divided by second element" ratio (best bang for your buck). However, as Example A demonstrate, this is not valid for all cases.

Is this a non-polynomial problem? If not, how can it be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: @FélixPoulin-Bélanger Different parts of the site feel differently about that. People who follow [algorithm] don't mind, but people who follow [python] and [performance] probably want more practical questions. This problem is weakly hard -- it's like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) except you're deciding which items to take out of the knapsack so that the weight limit is respected and you're trying to maximize the value remaining in the knapsack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 0-1 knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

The tuples are items, the first tuple elements are item values, the second tuple elements are item weights.  The classic knapsack asks "is `best` less than some particular limit.

As such, this problem is NP-complete and has no polynomial time solution.

There normal dynamic programming solution can be adapted to work in O(items.length * best).  The easiest way is to use the normal DP method, first with a small limit on best, and then doubling it until the target value is achievable.

Comment: Well, no *known* polynomial-time solution.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the knapsack problem! As I understand, it maximizes the sum of the values of the items in the knapsack so that the sum of the weights is less than or equal to a capacity. My problem is the opposite: minimize the sum of the weights of the items in the knapsack so that the sum of the values is greater than or equal to a target. However, that symmetry probably means that both problem are equivalent.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: I'm not sure this a 0-1 knapsack problem. The `items` input is a list, not a set. As such, each "item" can have a different maximum number of copies. For instance, in Example A, the item `(25,50)` can have two copies, but the other two items can only have one copy. But thanks for pointing me to the knapsack problem, reading more about it will definitely help me out!